# Having trouble tracing recursive method in Java

Tags: java, recursion

This is a rather quick question. I have been having trouble understanding the concept of recursion in Java and I was wondering if someone could help me. I have been tracing successfully 5 out of the 6 recursive methods that I have done, but this one is throwing me for a loop, literally. I was expecting the output to be just 2(the output I traced), but when I put it into my compiler it came out with 1213121(proper output). As I said, I have been able to do this thus far, but this one is confusing me. Here is what I am working with:

```
public class Recursion
{
    public static void main(String [] args)
    {
        Recursion r = new Recursion();
        r.doSomething(3);
    }

    public void doSomething(int n)
    {
        if (n > 0)
        {
            doSomething(n-1);
            System.out.print(n);
            doSomething(n-1);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: did you step though it with a debugger?

Comment: There seems nothing wrong about the proper output. Not sure about what do you mean by "I was expecting the output to be just 2(the output I traced)". Could you explain how you traced it?

Comment: doSomething(3) calls dosomething(2) prints 3 then calls doSomething(2) again.  doSomething(2) calls doSomething(1) then prints 2 and calls doSomething(1) again.  doSomething(1) calls doSomething(0) then prints 1 then calls doSomething(0) again.  doSomething(0) does nothing, so doSomething(1) actually just prints "1".  doSomething(2) is therefore "121". doSomething(3) is therefore "1213121".

Comment: Yeah but I still dont completely understand how its getting the int values it is

Comment: Just write each function call and replace it with what it outputs. You can easily do it on a piece of paper. Forget the debugger.

Comment: Thanks David. Running through it on paper and referencing what you wrote help. I see how the output is 1213121 now.

Comment: If that simple suggestion (to write the values on a piece of paper) worked for you, check this video on "hand execution." https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=di3AY0Msi20

Comment: Thanks, I will definitely check it out mark

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would prefer to do this in the comments, but the formatting of the comments make it hard to follow. You can follow this recursion as if it were a math equation.

The basic logic is:

DoSomething(n) results in:

- doSomething(n-1)
- print n
- doSomething(n-1)

So let's follow this for doSomething(3)

- doSomething(2)
- print 3
- soSomething(2)

So now we have to figure out what doSomething(2) does, so just plug in the values with n=2:

- doSomething(1)
- print 2
- doSomething(1)

Now plug in the values for n=1:

- doSomething(0)
- print 1
- doSomething(0)

doSomething(0) is the base case, where the recursion stops.  Basically doSomething(0) does nothing.

Therefore, the actions for n=1 become

- print 1

Therefore, the actions for n=2 become

- print 1
- print 2
- print 1

Therefore, the actions for n=3 become

- print 1
- print 2
- print 1
- print 3
- print 1
- print 2
- print 1

Comment: Thanks David. That makes a lot of sense and is easy to follow

Answer (score 3):

Here is the diagramatic representation of how the control flows through this recursion program.

I think the diagram should clear your doubts.

[image]

Comment: That's a good explanation.  Read it from left to right.  Output is: 1213121

Answer (score 0):

Let's give line numbers to below code to ease further explanation.

1. doSomething(n-1);
2. System.out.print(n);
3. doSomething(n-1);

   line 1 redirect call until you reach at n=1. In the end line will call doSomething(0). because n>0, it will return and will print 1. Then again line 3 will call doSomething(0) and will return to previous caller which was n=2.
   It will print 2 and will call doSomething(1). Which will print 1 (121) and will return to n=2,line3. From here it will return to previous caller where n=3. Line 2 will print 3(1213). Then line 3 will call doSomething(2) which will append 121 as previous call which will ultimately become 1213121.

I hope this helps.

---